# pointer from random access iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a random access iterator, and I need to turn it into a pointer (external API demands it!). I could do `T* ptr = &(*iter);`, but I find it rather ugly. Is there a better way? All random access iterators usually implement the `->` operator, but I am not aware of a generic way to just get the pointer to the data.

Comment: This being "ugly" stops it from being correct?

Comment: you can explicitly call the arrow operator but I'm not sure its any better: https://godbolt.org/z/heEdh5

Comment: You can remove the parentheses; don't know if you consider that less ugly.

Comment: @TanveerBadar Code can be correct and impossible to maintain. The two are not exclusive.

Comment: @Touloudou I didn't find it ugly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use C++20, there is [std::to_address](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/to_address). Example:

```
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};

int *ptr = std::to_address(v.begin());
```